# Check Original referer is google

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

in my web application i'm trying to check users are from google.com by this code:

```
$ref = request()->server('HTTP_REFERER');
if (strstr($ref, "google.com")) {
    $regex = '/q=(.+?)&/';
    preg_match($regex, $ref, $query);
    dd($query);
}
```

unfortunately i get null on `dd($query)`, how can i fix this code?

I think my `$regex` is not correct, i'm trying to check `google.com`

Comment: what it gives by dd($ref);

Comment: @Sohel0415 `https://www.google.com/`

Comment: why you are using regex, you are already done checking and inside the if block??

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes your right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str_constains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-contains):

```
if (str_contains(request()->headers->get('referer'), 'google.com')) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy no problem. )